# Incorrect JSDoc according to Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jsdoc

My grunt task jsdoc trips over this jsdoc which describes a an array of object literals :

```
/**
 * @type {{sku:string,
 *      stockColor:string,
 *      validTo:string,
 *      price:string,
 *      availableStock:string}[]} data
 *
 */
var variations = [];
```

The error message from Grunt is thus :

> D:\dev\ngs-frontend>grunt jsdoc Running "jsdoc:dist" (jsdoc) task
>
> > > ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file D:\dev\ngs-frontend\src\assets\js\modules\content\product-detail\hse-productdetails.js
> > >       with tag title "type" and text "{{sku:string,     stockColor:string,
> > >       validTo:string,     price:string,     availableStock:string}[]}":
> > >       Invalid type expression "{sku:string,     stockColor:string,
> > >       validTo:string,     price:string,     avail ableStock:string}[]":
> > >       Expected "!", "=", "?", "|" or end of input but "[" found.

As far as I know the JSDoc is correct from my part. Maybe there is a problem with the grunt jsdoc compiler?

I am defining an array of object literals. As far as I know this :

**{{name:value, name2:value2}[]}**

is the correct way of describing this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a *bug/unsupported syntax* of jsdoc itself (tried on with jsdoc 3.4.0), not grunt. You should probably report them the bug on https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/

The syntax `@type { {a : String, b : Number} }` is supported but not `@type { {a : String, b : Number}[] }`

You could work it around by using an `@typedef`, for example:

```
/**
 * @typedef { {
 *      sku:string,
 *      stockColor:string,
 *      validTo:string,
 *      price:string,
 *      availableStock:string }} variation
 */

/**
 * @type {variation[]} 
 */
var variations = [];
```